# Converting Image to Textual form to send over SMS

Tags: android, image, sms, binary-data, mms

Is there any way that i can convert image to textual representation so that i can send it via SMS and convert back to image after receiving on the other end. By doing this i'll be able to share media files without internet/mms i-e mms will be converted to sms.

I want to know that if it's even possible or not? if possible then how? The only issue is the conversion of images to text and vice versa.

Comment: You can google a litlle about BLOB format. Parse image to BLOB send them and transform back to image. Thats first thing on my mind and in my opinion easiest one

Comment: Certainly it's possible, but the maximum message size for SMS will restrict you to very small/low resolution images, even using data SMS. Though, I suppose you could split the message over several sends, but that might get kinda hairy.

Comment: Search for "binary sms".

Comment: @Mike M. Since typical length of an SMS being ~160, so it's again even affordable (as compared to network accessibility) to send image over multiple sms behind the scenes and receive over other end.

Comment: [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding is commonly used to represent binary data as "text".

Comment: You would be better of looking for a MMS provider. You will experience many issues on the the recipients end(image not displayed at all or as expected)if you try send images over a SMPP protocol

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, using binary coding through smpp protocol.

Depending on the gateway you are using, you'll be able to choose a binary coding and pass your content, even if your content will be longer than permitted 160 chars per sms, it'll be sent through multipart sms (many slices).